# Match digits or alphanumeric of variable length in a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using Perl to extract certain lines from a text file. The lines all start with and eleven character code like

```
 XXX   YXXXZZXX  Data to get
```

where `X` is always a digit, `Y` can be alphanumeric or missing, `Z` can be alphanumeric (specifically it can be `A` or a digit `0-9`. The other wrinkle is that sometimes this character code can be 12 characters long if the `Z` part is three characters instead of 2.

```
 XXX   YXXXZZZXX  Data to get
```

I can hardcode in the first three `X`'s and the `Y` but I need the code to be flexible for the `Z`. I essentially need to store the `Z`'s as an ID variable. For context, the first three letters indicate the question number in a survey that "Data to get" is the answer to. So suppose I'm looking for question `72` then (assuming `Y` isn't missing for Q72) the matching code I'm using is

```
 if(m{^072(\s+)YXXX(d\{2,3})(\d{2})(\s+)(.+)}){
      my $id = $2;
      my $Data = $5
 }
```

This seems to solve the 11 versus 12 character issue because the last `XX` in the 11 character code is always only two characters long. If the code is 12 characters long, the only part that increases is the `Z` part. So this should be able to capture all 2 and 3 digit id's (correct me if I'm wrong).

The problem is that sometimes the id will be `AA` (never `AAA`) and I need to make the code flexible enough so that the if statement will be executed for all 2 and 3 digit codes as well as potential `AA` id's.

I've tried

```
 if(m{^072(\s+)YXXX(.{2,3})(\d{2})(\s+)(.+)}){
      my $id = $2;
      my $Data = $5
 }
```

but I don't think it's working quite right. I think the `.` might be too flexible. Any suggestions on the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give example of what do you want to match and extract?

Comment: `072  C001AA00 Data to get` or `072  C0010300 Data to get` or `072  C00110200 Data to get`. The ID in the first one is `AA` the ID in the second one is `03` and the ID in the third one is `102`. Thanks.

Comment: Are the last two `XX` always 2 digits long? If so, you can leave `.{2,3}` and use `\d{2}` for the last XX instead. That'll fix the 'too flexible' part. Also note that you don't need to use parens around `\s+` or `\d+` if you don't need them either. You should be able to use `^072\s+YXXX(.{2,3})\d+\s+(.+)` and then get `my $id = $1; my $Data = $2`.

Comment: Hi @Jerry. Yeah the `XX` is always 2 digits long. I made a mistake in entering the code above. I've changed the post to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $id, $data ) = /^072\s+\w{4}(\w{2,3})\w{2}\s+(.+)/;
    print "ID: $id; Data: $data\n";
}

__DATA__
072 C001AA00 Data1 to get
072 C0010300 Data2 to get
072 C00110200 Data3 to get
```

Output:

```
ID: AA; Data: Data1 to get
ID: 03; Data: Data2 to get
ID: 102; Data: Data3 to get
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I have to do this for a lot of different questions, and this part of the code is already nested quite deeply, so I was hoping there is a way to do it all in one line by just altering my matching command. Is there a better way to find either `AA` or `0-9` than using `(.{2,3})`?

Comment: @MarkClements - See my revised answer.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that `\w` would capture digits as well as alphanumeric. I thought it would only capture alphanumeric characters. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @MarkClements - `\w` (for *word*) matches alphanumeric characters and the underscore "_".

Comment: @MarkClements alphanumeric is a term used for both letters and numbers. Alpha means the alphabet and numeric means numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> General Pattern : XXX YXXXZZXX Data to get
>
> where X is always a digit, Y can be alphanumeric or missing, Z can be
> alphanumeric (specifically it can be A or a digit 0-9. The other
> wrinkle is that sometimes this character code can be 12 characters
> long if the Z part is three characters instead of 2.

Trying to translate your specifications, I came up with this :

```
[\d]{3}\s*[\d\w]?[\d]{3}[A\d]{2,3}[\d]{2}\s*(.+)
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?38ejs

---

**UPDATE :**

And yet another demo (with all your test cases + match groups in) :

http://rubular.com/r/6asYzHqi5P

> 072  C001AA00 Data to get 1
>
> 072  C0010300 Data to get 2
>
> 072  C00110200 Data to get 3